# Global Mutator for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have many different locations ways of inserting and updating my database and I would like to be able to `trim()` the users input before inserting into the database. I know in the model I can do something like below, but I do not want to do this for every field. Is there a way to set a  generic setter that works on all fields?

Example:

```
public function setSomFieldAttribute($value) {
     return $this->attributes['some_field'] = trim($value);
}
```

Comment: In recent versions of Laravel ( >=5.4 ) there is a middleware out of the box to trim all input. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-middleware

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably will be able to override those methods:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected function getAttributeValue($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttributeValue($key);

        return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
       parent::setAttribute($key, $value);

        if (is_string($value))
        {
            $this->attributes[$key] = trim($value);
        }
    }
}
```

And you should never get an untrimmed value again.

EDIT:

Tested this here and I got no spaces:

```
Route::any('test', ['as' => 'test', function()
{
    $d = Post::find(2);

    $d->title_en = "  Markdown Example  ";

    dd($d);
}]);
```

Comment: the `setAttribute` function does not seem to be executing.

Comment: does this work when using something like this: `$callback->where('id', $id)->update(array($field => $value, 'modified_by' => $user['username'], 'modified_date' => $currentTime));` the only thing I can think is that my method of updating is nto supported by mutators.

Comment: Yeah, probably not, because you are generating a query from that statement. I don't think it will use mutators in this case, part of this job is done by Query Builder, which has almost nothing to do with Eloquent things.

Comment: Only if you are manually updating values. `$model->value = new value`. I think.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Model Events`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#events) for this and run `trim` on each field you want when creating or updating a model.

```
class Model extends \Eloquent {
    ...
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model){
            $model->some_field = trim($model->some_field);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Example usage:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->some_field = '  foobar    ';
$model->save();

// $model->some_field should now be trimmed
```

Comment: @arrowill12 as to me this answer should be accepted.